# getting this error:Trying to get property 'Date' of non-object - codeingniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I'm new in  codeigniter. I am trying to fetch data from the db to my view to display the data on the table below;  After running the codes i get this error:

> Trying to get property 'Date' of non-object.

view

```
 <?php foreach($consult as $value):?>

    <tr>
     <td><?php echo $value->Date ?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $value->Diagnosis ?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $value->Cost ?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $value->Balance ?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $value->recomendation ?></td> 
     <td>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"></a>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"></a>
     </td>   
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Controller

```
  $all_tests =  $this->singletest_model->get_consult($id);

  $data = array();

  foreach($all_tests->result() as $key=> $r) {
    $button='';
    // $rowid="'".$r->consultancy_id."'".",'".$r->Date."'";
    $rowid1=$r->consultancy_id;
    $idd=$r->consultancy_id;
    $button .=  '
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void()"  title="prescriptions" onclick=" viewconsult('.$id.','.$rowid1.')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> View</a>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalDeleteTest" title="Delete" onclick="deletetest('.$rowid1.')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModaleditest" title="prescriptions" onclick="prescribe('.$id.','.$rowid1.')">Add Prescription</a>';
       $data[] = array(
            $r->Date,
            $r->Diagnosis,
            $r->recomendation,
            $r->Cost,
            $r->Balance,
            $button
            );
  }
```

model

```
 public function get_consult($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('consult');
    $this->db->join('patients', 'consult.Patient_Id = patients.pat_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('consultancy_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You put object values into an array, but not the entire object:

```
...
$data[] = array(
            $r->Date,
            $r->Diagnosis,
            $r->recomendation,
            $r->Cost,
            $r->Balance,
            $button
            );
...
```

Now in view you can use this as array of course:

```
<?php foreach($consult as $value):?>

    <tr>
     <td><?php echo $value['Date'] ?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $value['Diagnosis'] ?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $value['Cost'] ?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $value['Balance'] ?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $value['recomendation'] ?></td> 
     <td>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"></a>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"></a>
     </td>   
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use 'result_array' instead of 'result'. Date is a reserved value, so it might conflict. I changed your code to the array variant.

```
<?php

$all_tests = $this->singletest_model->get_consult($id);

$data = array();

foreach($all_tests->result_array() as $key => $r) {
    $button = '';
    $rowid1 = $r['consultancy_id'];
    $id = $r['consultancy_id'];

    $button .=  '
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void()"  title="prescriptions" onclick=" viewconsult('.$id.','.$rowid1.')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> View</a>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalDeleteTest" title="Delete" onclick="deletetest('.$rowid1.')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModaleditest" title="prescriptions" onclick="prescribe('.$id.','.$rowid1.')">Add Prescription</a>';
    $data[] = array(
        $r['Date'],
        $r['Diagnosis'],
        $r['recomendation'],
        $r['Cost'],
        $r['Balance'],
        $button
    );
}
```